# Can distutils perform a dependency check without installing?

Tags: python, distutils, setup.py

Is it possible to have distutils just run the python module dependency analysis (and possibly install missing modules) without actually installing the python module in question? I imagine a command as follows:

```
./setup.py check-dependencies
```

that would report if any dependent modules are missing on the target system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the closest you can get is:

```
setup.py install -v -n
```

which means to run a dry-run (`-n`) in verbose (`-v`) mode.

You could also use the [distuitls.dep_util](http://docs.python.org/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.dep_util) module, it wouldn't work as an option of `setup.py` though.

HTH!

Comment: That’s lucky, as the dry-run mode is broken for some commands.  (I’ll be working on fixing that but it’s not trivial to write unit tests for the fixed behavior).

Answer (score 5):

Dependencies in Python packaging are a confusing subject.  For a long time, the only standard was PEP 314, which defines the `requires`, `provides` and `obsoletes` parameter to the `distutils.core.setup` function.  The elements used for these arguments are Python module name, for example `provides=['xml', 'xml.utils']`.  The PEP was not very clear about standard library dependencies (do I have to depend on Python >= 2.5 or do I have to require `'xml'`?) and as it turned out, there was no tool that made use of these fields (not even distutils itself).

Then came setuptools.  It introduced other kinds of dependencies which used *project* names instead of *modules*, so for example you can have `setup(..., install_requires=['PyXML', 'Pylons'], tests_require=['nose'])`, which is immensely more useful: people release software on PyPI using unique project names, and you can use these same names in your setup script to depend on them, and with easy_install or pip you get these dependencies installed, modules, scripts and all.

When the reins of distutils were taken up again a few years ago, the community standardized some of setuptools’ idea of dependencies to produce PEP 345, which is now implemented in distutils2, intended to replace distutils and setuptools.

To sum it all up:
- you may have distutils-style module-level dependencies in your setup script, which are useless
- you may have setuptools-style project-level deps, which are used by setuptools-based tools
- you can have PEP 345-compliant projec-level deps in a `setup.cfg` file, which are used by distutils2

So, to let us answer your question, you need to tell us which kind you have.  For all practical matters, distutils-style module deps should not be used, so it leaves setuptools project deps or the new PEP 345-style ones, which are still new and not widespread yet.  distutils2 has a compat layer for setuptools, so it can be possible to use it to get the info you want out of a setuptools-based `setup.py` script.

Unrelated to packaging tools, there is also a tool that can scan your code to find the modules you’re using: it’s the modulefinder module, in the standard library, which is not very known or used, judging by the sad state of its code.  This tool won’t tell you if a module used comes from the stdlib or a third-party project, and it can’t tell you the project name to use in your `setup.py` or `setup.cfg` file.

HTH

Comment: So you’re asking about project dependencies, not modules.  setup scripts have metadata querying options, like `python setup.py --name`; sadly, setuptools does not support `python setup.py --install-requires`.

Answer (score 0):

distutils.dep_util is concerned about file dependencies (i.e. if somefile.c is newer than somefile.o, then somefile.o needs to be re-compiled), not project dependencies.  [wanted to add this as a comment on the other reply but apparently the Add comment button adds an answer?]

Comment: Hm, add comment should add a comment to the answer.