# example of python distutils package code that depends on other modules?

Tags: python, installation, distribution, distutils, package-managers

can someone point out a simple example of making a Python package using distutils that depends on *other* python modules being installed, e.g. numpy (a particular version) and scipy?  I found very simple examples online but could not find an example that depends on a known package. I want to find the easiest system where such dependencies are installed for the user when the user installs the package I am defining using setup.py install.  thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Distutils` by itself does not install dependencies.  You need to use an add-on to Distutils, like [`pip`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) or plain [`Distribute/setuptools`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute).

Comment: It's all documented here:  http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#declaring-dependencies

Comment: Also, we’re talking about project-level dependencies, not module-level; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8419012/821378